# How to solve error in socket.io?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, socket.io

I tried to do a example in socket.io.. My client.js code is :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

My server.js code is :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

When i execute this .. I got error as :

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

    at Module._compile (module.js:427:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)    
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)   
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12) 
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Looks like you have an unexpected < in your node.js code somewhere else. Do you have some html in a string somewhere in the server?

Comment: Could you post your server code somewhere? Private if necessary? Its definitely an error in the node code

Answer (score 0):

Your file `client.js` is a javascript file, and should not have HTML-like tags like `<script>`.

Comment: I changed it to client.html... Is dat correct? When i execute , i got the same error as above

Comment: @Micku How do you "execute" it?

Comment: When i execute it using browser, it shows only a blank page... not displaying anything... So i tried command 'node filename' . But it shows the error

Comment: 'node filename' is the wrong way to do it, getting an error about an illegal '<' is exactly what you'd expect.  Having it as an .html file and loading it with your browser is correct.  After you've loaded it with your browser and you get a blank page, can you open up the browser's debug mode/debug console (IE Chrome and Firefox all have pretty good debug modes)?  Then you can look to see if there are javascript errors, whether it has found and successfully loaded "socket.io.js", etc.

Comment: The reason for your web page showing blank couldbe that your <script> is executing before socket.io.js has finished loading, you might try onload()